# Can an Android app modify the audio system of the device?

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I've received a bug report from an user of my app. She said that after downloaded my app and used it, the speaker of the mobile phone didn't emit any sound anymore, even after deleting the app. She solved the problem only after restarting the device in safe mode.
Is it really possible that my app caused this? Have you heard about similar cases?

The app is an audio player for an audio codec not supported by Android versions previous to 5.0. 
I've used the `AudioTrack` class for playing the audio and a custom decoder made with the Java Native Interface and a third part library written in C.
The device is a Galaxy A3 (2017) with Android 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the app some months ago, substituting the old deprecated `AudioTrack` constructor with the new one that make use of the `AudioTrack.Builder`. I haven't received new similar report, so maybe the problem is solved.